# iOS internal audio recording

Tags: ios, audio

My iOS app is an musical instrument and I want to make a record of playing, but without using mic. 
Any suggestion or at least direction will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use buffers to write them into a file. Audio units or Audio Queues.

Comment: Actually audio queues. This is one of the primary reasons that framework even exists. if you try to write the file from the audio unit render callback you risk stalling an ultra high priority thread and glitching the matrix.

Comment: So, play using Audio Units and Record using Audio Queues?

Answer (score 1):

my curiosity...  ex. if its a musical instrument(ex piano or keyboard), on pressing any key, it should play some sound. In your app, while playing sound(tone 1, tone 2)on pressing the key, create a new file(.mp3 or .midi) & write the data to it. But, you should be familiar with sound file internals(headers, body ....etc)